# How to clean from non working files?

Tags: data-recovery

I did file recovery using in Windows "Recuva" using deep scan so that recovered a lot bad non working files and im reviewing files in Ubuntu. So some files are opening and some not. Can i somehow clean or select bad files to move them to another folder?

Answer (score -1):

Use  [BleachBit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux). I guess this is default in Ubuntu.

Comment: 0H i found its in Ubuntu also. But how to check file integrity or workability?

Comment: Its not for that. Its not for checking if file is workable if its working and good file.. This programm is for system cleanup/janitazoring.

Comment: i donn't know if we can check integrity. but it is useful to clean HD

Comment: why negative vote? People should tell what is wrong.